# How to declare a variable in SQL script?

Tags: mysql, sql, ubuntu

Just installed sql on ubuntu 21.04.

```
$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 8.0.26-0ubuntu0.21.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

Wrote a `test.sql` file:

```
declare @a as int=4
```

On executing `mysql> source /home/home/test.sql` on the command line, the following error is returned:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare @a as int=4' at line 1
```

adding `begin` and `end` to the script doesn't help either. What is the fix?

Comment: any reason you are using mysql instead of mariadb?

Comment: no particular reason. I do not know what is mariadb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use declared variables in stored procedure. In an ordinary SQL script, use user variables, which are names beginning with `@`. You don't specify a type, they can hold any type of value.

```
SET @a = 4;
```

Comment: thanks. this didn't return any error. How can I print the value of the variable? ```print @a``` is not working.  Also, how to perform mathematical operations? ```@a=@a+1``` does not work.

Comment: what is 'stored procedure'?

Comment: Tutorial: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx

Answer (score 2):

First you need to declare the variable

```
DECLARE @MyVariable INT;
```

and then you can set it

```
SET @MyVariable = 1;
```